# How to pass 2D array from Javascript to Spring Boot function in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get 2D array from javascript to spring boot function in Java and it doesn't work. Here is my code.[image: code in Javasscript][image: code in Java]
Is there someone who knows how to do it? 1D array isn't problem to do like this. Is it possible with this form or should I use something else?

Comment: What's does "not working" mean? Are you getting errors? If so what? Have you tried to set the content-type to application/json?

Comment: Also you are sending an object, which in JSON would be a JSON object. So you would need to make a wrapper class to hold the matrix. Or remove the object from the request and just send the matrix.

Comment: This is the WARN what i get
2020-12-03 08:37:45.089  WARN 28122 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Integer[][] parameter 'matrixA[][]' is not present]

Comment: I don't understand this "Or remove the object from the request and just send the matrix ". How are you mean it ?

Comment: Remove the `{}`. That makes it an object. Do you understand how JSON maps to Java objects?

Comment: Set the content-type to application/json

Comment: Get rid of the `@RequestParam` and put `@RequestBody`

Answer (score 0):

By the way your data object is constructed:
`data: {matrixA: ...}`
the backend is expecting an object with a field matrixA, instead of a matrix. In your controller, define a class to encapsulate the matrixA and use that as a RequestParam.

Moreover, you can always inspect the actual request being sent in browser's developer tools, network tab.

Secondly, javascript arrays can be automatically mapped to lists in Java by (almost) all serialization libraries, so you could use a `List<List<Integer>>` to map your matrix if that is more convenient.

If you don't want to encapsulate your request in an object with the field `matrixA`, you could send matrixA directly in the `data` field: `data: matrixA`, and expect a List<List> in the controller.